# JQuery .html(), .val() and onclick="" missing attribute value

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

JQuery 1.7.2.

Have a html:

```
<div id="div1">
<a class="picture" href="images/1.jpg" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"><img src="images/1s.jpg" /></a> 
</div>
<p><span id="constructorview">To text area</span></p>
<p><textarea id="text1"></textearea></p>
```

And have JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#constructorview').live('click',function() {
$('#text1').val($('#div1').html());
});
});
```

After clicking #constructorview textarea value set to:

"return hs.expand(this)" is missing!

P.S. After first time it works. Then I save to database. Next time it sets to onclick="".

Please help me!

How to save onclick attribute value???

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: is this working http://jsfiddle.net/naMJ9/ ?

Comment: After spelling /textarea correctly, it shows the onclick correctly in chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#text1').val($('#div1').html());
```

In this scenario it will not return dom elements in textarea using val attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#text1').html($('#div1').html());
```

and edit `<textarea id="text1"></textearea>` to `<textarea id="text1"></textarea>`
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xSX94/)

Comment: no textarea have .html check live demo on fiddle!!!!! .html for container tag like div p textarea and .val for non-container tag like input

Comment: yes, I saw it. Removed the downvote and comment. I would STILL you .val because it makes more sense from a form input element point of view

Answer (score 0):

`live()` is deprecated in updated jQuery versions, it is better to use `on()` instead and assign html as html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#constructorview').on('click',function() {
        $('#text1').html($('#div1').html());
    });
});
```